# google-api-client dependencies in java doesnt work

Tags: java, maven, google-api, dependencies

I have inserted the following dependencies in my project:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.32.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.32.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My imports and my code is as follows:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;


       GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
            // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
            .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
            // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
            //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
            .build();

        // (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)

        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(googleToken);
        if (idToken != null) {
          Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

          // Print user identifier
          String userId = payload.getSubject();
          System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

          // Get profile information from payload
          String email = payload.getEmail();
          boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
          String name = (String) payload.get("name");
          String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
          String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
          String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
          String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

          // Use or store profile information
          // ...

        } else {
          System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
        }
```

I don't know why but the Google classes and imports give me an error without telling me why. I think it may be something that I have not done well with the dependencies but I do not know.

Comment: a) please  update the question with error message; b) is it multimodule project or not?

Comment: Did you try to resolve (download) the dependencies yet?

Answer (score 0):

When you put the dependencies in pom.xml, you need to update the maven project first. It is not worth with compile.